# How to use iset with nested datatype and lenses?

Tags: haskell, indices, haskell-lens, custom-data-type

I can't get the types in the last function to line up. Point is to set the all price Doubles in connections with a function that depends only on the index of the 3-tuple. The original Double value in the tuple can be discarded.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Control.Lens

data Typex = Typex 
    { _level       :: Int
    , _coordinate  :: (Int, Int)
    , _connections :: [(Int, (Int, Int), Double)]  -- = (level, coordinate, price)
    } deriving Show
makeLenses ''Typex

initTypexLevel :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Typex] 
initTypexLevel a b c = [ Typex a (x, y) [(0,(0,0),0.0)]
                       | x <- [0..b], y <- [0..c]
                       ]

buildNestedTypexs :: [(Int, Int)] -> [[Typex]]
buildNestedTypexs pts
     = setConnectionsx [ initTypexLevel i y y
                      | (i,(_,y)) <- zip [0..] pts
                      ]

setConnectionsx :: [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]
setConnectionsx (x:rest@(y:_)) = map (connect y) x : setConnectionsx rest
  where connect :: [Typex] -> Typex -> Typex
        connect txs tx
          = tx & connections .~ (map ((tx ^. level) + 1, , 0.0) $ txs ^.. traverse.coordinate)
setConnectionsx lst = lst

setInitPrices  :: [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]
setInitPrices  (x:rest) = map setIndexPrices x : setInitPrices  rest
  where setIndexPrices :: Typex -> Typex
        setIndexPrices tx =  n & connections .~ ??? -- using iset (?), set the price in every 3-tuple so that price = f (index of the 3-tuple) where f = i*2
setInitPrices  lst = lst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
  where setIndexPrices :: Typex -> Typex
        setIndexPrices tx =  tx & connections .> traversed <. _3 .@~ f
        f i = 2 * fromIntegral i
```

Here, `.@~` is the operator version of `iset`, and `.>` and `<.` are variants of the composition operator `.` used to combine indexed optics.

If you consider the simpler unindexed optic:

```
connections . traverse . _3
```

This optic takes a `TypeX`, focuses on its `_connections` fields, traverses the list of connections, and focuses on the third field (the price) of each connection.  The result is an optic that traverses all the prices in the `TypeX` in order.

To index this optic, we need to "upgrade" the unindexed `traverse` to the indexed `traversed`.  Then, we want to use the index-preserving composition operators `.>` and `<.` where the less/greater than signs point to the part of the optic that has the index we want.  (In more complicated scenarios with multiple indexes, you can use `<.>` to combine indexes from two optics into index pairs `(i,j)`.)

That's how we get:

```
connections .> traversed <. _3
```

It still traverses all the prices in the `TypeX` in order, but it also carries around the index from the traversal.

Note that `setInitPrices` is actually one of those functions that's easily written as an "all at once" lens computation.  The `map setIndexPrices` and recursion just traverse the nested list, so they're the equivalent of the optic `traverse . traverse`.  So, we can use:

```
setInitPrices' :: [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]
setInitPrices' = traverse .> traverse .> connections .> traversed <. _3 .@~ f
  where f i = 2 * fromIntegral i
```

Finally, it's maybe worth noting that if you have a complicated indexed optic like:

```
a .> b .> c .> d <. e <. f <. g
```

for obscure reasons (right associativity of the operators and the fact that `.>` is identical to `.`) this is always equivalent to:

```
a . b . c .> d <. e . f . g
```

and this is the more common way to write it.  So, the final version of `setInitPrices'` would be:

```
setInitPrices' :: [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]
setInitPrices' = traverse . traverse . connections .> traversed <. _3 .@~ f
  where f i = 2 * fromIntegral i
```

Comment: Excactly what I needed. Thank you for the detailed explanation as well. The example in this question works flawlessly but using it in my own code produces the following error: `* Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `traverse'
      prevents the constraint `(Traversable t0)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        setInitPrices' :: t0 (t1 MyType) -> t0 (t1 MyType) 
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0' should be`
The function type is clearly stated so what annotation could this mean?

Comment: This message is claiming that `setinitPrices'` doesn't have a type signature.  Did you maybe spell the function names differently in the type signature and definition?